# Condição dentro da cláusula WHERE

Tags: oracle, select, pl-sql, oracle11g, where

Boa tarde !
  Estou com uma tarefa de realizar um select, porém os parâmetros são passados como variáveis e preciso tratar a entrada de uma dessas variaveis com a seguinte lógica: se &CT não for nula, então eu adiciono na condição do select os valores que foram sugeridos nessa variavel, se ela for nula, então não quero executar essa condição no filtro select.
   Estou trabalhando com PL/SQL Oracle.

```
select * from TABELA t 
WHERE TRUNC(T.DATASTAMP) BETWEEN '&DATA_INICIAL' AND '&DATA_FINAL'
AND ( CASE WHEN &CT IS NOT NULL THEN T.CENTRO_TRABALHO = &CT END );
```

dessa forma está dando erro, tanto colocando valor na variavel como deixando ela nula.

Comment: não pode ser feito assim, o `case when` deve retornar um valor, baseado em vários casos, e comparar com algo no final, por exemplo: `where campo = (case campo2=1 then 10 else 20 end)`, irá sempre comparar "campo" com um valor que depende do "campo2"

Answer (score 2):

Você apenas necessita uma condição `or` no seu filtro:

```
...
and (&CT is null or T.CENTRO_TRABALHO = &CT)
```

Outra alternativa, provavelmente mais performática que o Or, seria utilizar a função [nvl](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) na sua variável, se for null, retorna o próprio campo que pode ser filtrado:

```
...
and NVL(&CT, T.CENTRO_TRABALHO) = T.CENTRO_TRABALHO
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode filtrar da seguinte forma:

```
select * from TABELA t 
WHERE TRUNC(T.DATASTAMP) BETWEEN '&DATA_INICIAL' AND '&DATA_FINAL'
AND 1 = ( CASE WHEN &CT IS NOT NULL AND T.CENTRO_TRABALHO = &CT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
```